# Using printer from Racket

Tags: printing, scheme, racket

How can I send a string to the printer from a Racket program? I tried to find examples on the internet but could not find it. The Racket documentation has these pages but how to send string to printer is not clear: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/printing.html  https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html
Thanks for your comments/answers.

Comment: It's a challenge since printing in these documents are to screen. They have nothing to do with printing to paper.

Comment: Perhaps you could try creating a PDF and then calling the printer via system call ?

Comment: Yes, I found that to be one option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/printer-dc_.html) suggests that you need to create a `printer-dc%` object and draw to that. When you are done, call the `end-doc` method to send a request to the OS to actually do the printing.